# Data frame regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below list with Regex patterns and other values in the list, and other info related to the pattern.

```
Regexes = ['.*PERSONAL[\W]*ACC(((OU)?N)?T|N(UM|BR|O(?![A-Z]))).*', 'ACC INFO', 'IDENTIFICATION INFO', '.*(ADDRESS|(|\b)ADDR)([\W]*LINE|LN)?[\W]\d', 'ADDRESS', 'ADDRESS INFO', '.(_|\b)(GE?NDE?R|SEX|MALE|FEMALE)(_|\b).', 'GENDER INFO', 'BIOGRAPHIC INFO', '(CHE(CK|QUE)|.*CHE(CK|QUE)[_\W]N(UM|BR|O(?![A-Z])).)','INSTRUMENT_NUMBER', 'FINANCIAL INFO']
```

The above list has values for, regex pattern, sensitive type and sensitive category. The above list is just an example, i have something like more than 400 regex patterns.

The first element is regex pattern and second is senstive_type and third element is senstive_category.

I have a data frame like below

INPUT:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| NAME                              |SENSITIVE_TYPE       | SENSTIVE_CATEGORY |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| PERSONAL_NUMBER                   |                     |                   |
| GENDER FLAG                       |                     |                   |
| SEX_FLAG                          |                     |                   |
| CHECK_NUMBER                      |                     |                   |
| CHECK_NO                          |                     |                   |
| ADDRESS_1                         |                     |                   |
| ADDRESS_2                         |                     |                   |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

So, the code should loop through NAME column in the dataframe and if NAME column matches with the regex pattern from the first element in the list then the code should update the sensitive_type and sensitive_category columns in the data frame from the associated values in the list.

OUTPUT:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| NAME                              |SENSITIVE_TYPE       | SENSTIVE_CATEGORY  |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| PERSONAL_NUMBER                   | ACC INFO            | IDENTIFICATION INFO|
| GENDER FLAG                       | GENDER INFO         | BIOGRAPHIC INFO    |
| SEX_FLAG                          | GENDER INFO         | BIOGRAPHIC INFO    |
| CHECK_NUMBER                      | INSTRUMENT NUMBER   | FINANCIAL INFO     |
| CHECK_NO                          | INSTRUMENT NUMBER   | FINANCIAL INFO     |
| ADDRESS_1                         | ADDRESS             | ADDRESS INFO       |
| ADDRESS_2                         | ADDRESS             | ADDRESS INFO       |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Code:

```
import sys
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:\samples\data.csv')

Regexes = ['.*PERSONAL[_\\W]*ACC(((OU)?N)?T|N(UM|BR|O(?![A-Z]))).*', 'ACC INFO', 'IDENTIFICATION INFO', 
'.*(ADDRESS|(_|\\b)ADDR)([_\\W]*LINE|LN)?[_\\W]*\\d*', 'ADDRESS', 'ADDRESS INFO', 
'.*(_|\\b)(GE?NDE?R|SEX|MALE|FEMALE)(_|\\b).*', 'GENDER INFO', 'BIOGRAPHIC INFO',
'(CHE(CK|QUE)|.*CHE(CK|QUE)[_\\W]*N(UM|BR|O(?![A-Z])).*)','INSTRUMENT NUMBER', 'FINANCIAL INFO']

regex_pattern= Regexes[0::3]
senstive_category=Regexes[1::3]
senstive_type=Regexes[2::3]

for result in df.NAME:
    if re.search(regex_pattern, result): 
        df.assign(SENSITIVE_CATEGORY=[Regex_cat])
        df.assign(SENSITIVE_TYPE=Regex_type)
        print(df)
    else:
        pass
```

I am not sure how to achieve the above? Any solution suggestion would be great.

Note: Also the whole Regex List can also be created as a data frame, but i even don't how to code with two data frames and get the desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Make your regex list a dict
rdict = dict(zip(Regexes[0::3],np.delete(np.asarray(Regexes).reshape(4,3), 0, 1).tolist()))

#get list of keys from dict
keys = [*rdict]

#Check for value then replace
for reg in keys:
    df.loc[df['NAME'].str.contains(reg, regex = True), 'SENSITIVE_TYPE'] = rdict[reg][0]
    df.loc[df['NAME'].str.contains(reg, regex = True), 'SENSTIVE_CATEGORY'] = rdict[reg][1]

    NAME             SENSITIVE_TYPE      SENSTIVE_CATEGORY
0   PERSONAL_NUMBER  ACC INFO            IDENTIFICATION INFO
1   GENDER FLAG      GENDER INFO         BIOGRAPHIC INFO
2   SEX_FLAG         GENDER INFO         BIOGRAPHIC INFO
3   CHECK_NUMBER     INSTRUMENT NUMBER   FINANCIAL INFO
4   CHECK_NO         INSTRUMENT NUMBER   FINANCIAL INFO
5   ADDRESS_1        ADDRESS             ADDRESS INFO
6   ADDRESS_2        ADDRESS             ADDRESS INFO
```

Although not the most elegant way, one way is to first make your Regexes list a dict. Then check if each row contains the regex from the key to the dict, and replace it with its corresponding value.

Comment: Also for `'.*PERSONAL[_\\W]*ACC(((OU)?N)?T|N(UM|BR|O(?![A-Z]))).*'` The `(` after ACC should be before ACC.

Comment: That's Terrific. The solution worked perfectly.  Thank you very much for the solution.